# ggplot2 add background colour to legend title

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to change the background colour of only the legend title (not the entire legend).

If I start with the below code:

```
library(ggplot2)
#produce a ggplot
ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, colour=Species)) + 
  geom_point()
```

I can use `theme( legend.title = element_rect( fill = "lightblue",  size = 0.5, linetype = "solid", colour = "black"))` to change the background of the entire legend which isnt what I am after.

Is there anyway to just change the background colour of the *legend title* ?

Comment: No, there isn't, at least not without serious hacking. The `legend.title`  must be an `element_text()` and this only has a `colour` argument, not a `fill` one.

Comment: @RuiBarradas you're right about that if you stick entirely to ggplot, but it's pretty trivial to do this using ggtext. This has an `element_textbox` that can be assigned to the legend title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, using the ggtext package, one can do

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

ggplot(iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Sepal.Width, colour=Species)) + 
  geom_point() +
  theme(legend.title = element_textbox(fill = 'red', color = 'white'))
```

[image]